# No Deadlock - but why? Four conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have a Producer Consumer problem and solved it by using semaphores but cannot formally explain which of the four conditions necessary for deadlock I have prevented. It can't be mutual exclusive access or non preemption which leaves either circular-wait or hold and wait. I clearly try to acquire two resources in both the insert and take methods, which hints to hold and wait being existing. Now there's only circular-wait left which I should have prevented but how? Or is my reasoning wrong and it's not circular-wait?

**Edit:** As people have repeatedly asked me what the problem is with my code because deadlock cannot happen, I want to say there's nothing wrong with it, I just want to know **WHY** it cannot happen. There are four conditions which need to be met for deadlock to occur which can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions . I obviously prevented at least one condition or otherwise my code could result in a deadlock. Now I just want to know **WHICH** of the conditions I prevented.

My Buffers code looks like this:

```
private String[] store;
private int capacity;

private int nextIn;
private int nextOut;

private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
private Semaphore numAvail = new Semaphore(0); //available items to consume
private Semaphore numFree; //free slots in buffer

public Buffer(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.store = new String[capacity];
    numFree = new Semaphore(capacity);
}

public void insert(String item) {

    try {
        //acquire a free slot in the array
        numFree.acquire();

        //get permit to insert
        mutex.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    //critical region - insert to body
    store[nextIn] = item;

    nextIn++;

    //when at end of array begin at index 0 again
    if (nextIn == capacity) {
        nextIn = 0;
    }

    //signal that there is an item available
    numAvail.release();

    //signal that another thread can consume or produce now
    mutex.release();
}

public String take() {
    String item;

    try {
        //check if item exists to consume
        numAvail.acquire();

        //get permit to take
        mutex.acquire();

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //critical region
    item = store[nextOut];

    nextOut++;

    if (nextOut == capacity) {
        nextOut = 0;
    }


    //signal other threads that they can consume or produce
    mutex.release();

    //signal that there is a free slot to insert now
    numFree.release();

    return item;
}
```

Comment: but, .. you do not have any possibility of deadlock in this code. what are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I solved it but wanted to understand the reason how, that's what my question is about

Comment: the question is, what did you have before, which created the dead lock. If you called `insert` from `take` after locking a semaphore (btw, why do you need 2 of them?), then you prevented "hold and wait" by just removing the call. Do not pay much attention to names. Just think what you did and for what reason.

Comment: No I have never had a deadlock, I'm just not sure which of the four conditions necessary for it I have prevented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you prevented circular wait.

Circular wait occurs when [each process waits for a resource which is being held by another process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions).

In your example, the only resource that is being waited for while holding another resource is the mutex. However, a thread that holds the mutex does never wait for anything.

For circular wait to occur, the mutex-holding thread would need to wait for something while having the mutex.